# how to clear kendo spreadsheet on ajax success event?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo UI spreadsheet that is working fine except one issue that is to clear whole spreadsheet on ajax Success, How to clear whole spreadsheet on success?

Comment: i could not try anything yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the whole spreadsheet you can do

$("#spreadsheet").remove();

To remove only one sheet you can use removeSheet method.

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, you want to clear the data from the spreadsheet rather than make the whole control disappear, then you can do this:

```
  var spreadsheet = $("#spreadsheet").getKendoSpreadsheet();

  var sheet = spreadsheet.activeSheet();

  sheet.range(kendo.spreadsheet.SHEETREF).clear();
```

Tested it and it works